# @Schedule executed in random moments

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.1, wildfly

I have some code running within wildfly:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderStatusMonitorScheduler {

    @Inject
    private OrderEntityDao orderEntityDao;

    @Inject
    private TradeAgentClientSender tradeAgentClientSender;

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*", hour="*", persistent = false)
    public void queryOrderStatusesBatch() {
        log.debug("queryOrderStatusesBatch start");
        ....
    }
}
```

sometimes the scheduler executes every second, but there are times when there are 15-30 seconds periods between writing "queryOrderStatusesBatch start" to log file. Sometimes the frequency between subsequent calls is higher (several times per second). What could be the reason? Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How time-consuming is logic inside the method `queryOrderStatusesBatch`? I think that the reason of 15-30 periods of silence between invocaiton of this method can be limited threads number.  Timer Service uses thread pool to run scheduled tasks. If logic inside `@Schedule` annotated method is time-consuming and is performed often then the next invocation may not happen because there is no free thread to run a task.
Timer Service thread pool can be configured e.g. via administration console in application server.

Regarding the higher freequency between subsequent calls - the reason can be rolled back transaction associated with `@Schedule` annotated method. In the example you presented the transaction type for method `queryOrderStatusesBatch` is `REQUIRED`. If logic you implemented there throws an exception then transaction is automatically rolled back. Moreover the container is obliged to retry timeout method.